# DOM Nodes keep on increasing in my Angular

Tags: html, angular, dom, memory-leaks, subscription

I have an issue with my Angular 8 app where the DOM nodes keep on increasing and it never decreases. I did unsubscribe all subscriptions in the ngOnDestroy() hook, I still see DOM nodes not decreasing. Can someone tell me how to clear those DOM nodes when I leave that component?

Comment: Can you give your code snippet so that we can understand better. Normally unsubcribe is  for service object garbage collection. There is no relationship with dom element.